# selenium + chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry = invalid calling page error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Selenium script to test a Chrome app that uses the Chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry API to select a directory. When I do this manually, it works fine. But when I do this in a Selenium script, I get back this error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running fileSystem.chooseEntry: Invalid calling page. This function can't be called from a background page.

Any ideas on how to make Selenium and chooseEntry play nicely together?

I updated to the latest Chromedriver, but still no luck. I also looked at ChromeOptions, but didn't see anything that looked like it would be helpful. The interwebs doesn't seem to have much to say about Selenium and chooseEntry. I'm on version 51 of Chrome.

I'm down to thinking I'll need a special javascript entry point to set the path values for testing instead of using chooseEntry. But I would strongly prefer to not have a separate code execution path for my tests. Anybody have a cleaner solution?

EDIT: per commenter's request, here's the offending code:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:'openDirectory'},function(entry) {
  chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(entry,function(writeable_entry) {
      console.log("got writeable entry");
  });
 }, function(e) { errorHandler(e); });
```

EDIT #2: I've gone with the special javascript entry point hack. In manual mode -- i.e., not running under Selenium -- I run code that executes chooseEntry, and then use the retainEntry API to get the entry id. I added an entry point in my javascript to take an entry id and call the restoreEntry API to turn it back into an entry. I also modified my code so if this entry object is set, then use that as the file instead of calling chooseEntry. Lastly, I modified my Selenium script to call the restoreEntry entry point before running the rest of the script.

This is not ideal, since now my test code execution path is somewhat different from my actual live-human-being-at-the-controls code execution path. But at least it lets me use Selenium scripts now. Of course, if anyone can think of a non-horrible way to solve this solution, I'd love to hear about it.

EDIT #3: Per @Xan's comment, corrected my terminology from "extension" to "Chrome App."

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: `chrome.fileSystem` **is not an extension API**, it's only available to Chrome Apps. So, what are you writing?

Comment: Whoops, you are 100% correct. I've updated my post to use the correct terminology. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer this horrible hack.   For Chrome Apps under OSX I created folder favorites and use Robot keyPress to navigate and select the 'favorite' folders needed for the App.  The only possible redeeming factor is that it does mirror a valid/possible actual human interaction with the file interface.

```
private void selectOSXFolderFavorite(int favorite) {

    // With an OSX file folder dialog open, Shift-Tab to favorites list
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

    // move to the top of favorites list
    int i = 40;
    while (i-- > 0) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    }
    while (favorite-- > 0) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    }

    // Send an enter key to Select the selected folder
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Comment: Hi Embarrassed :) Thanks for code snippet. Unfortunately, I need one of Chrome's FileEntry or DirectoryEntry objects to do my later work, which means I have to use the chooseEntry API to pick my destination and create the Entry object. And it's chooseEntry that throws the error when running under Selenium.